# Xamarin Android merge audio files with FFMpeg

Tags: xamarin, ffmpeg, xamarin.android, android-ffmpeg

I am using this binding library for FFMpeg:
https://github.com/gperozzo/XamarinAndroidFFmpeg

My goal is to mix two audio files.

```
String s = "-i " + "test.wav" + " -i " + test2.mp3 + " -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first " + "result.mp3";

Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
   await FFMpeg.Xamarin.FFmpegLibrary.Run(Forms.Context, s);
});
```

So I have 2 input files: one is .mp3 and another one is .wav.

I've tried also next commands:

```
String s= "-i "+ "test.wav" +" -i "+ "test2.mp3" + " -filter_complex [0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out] -map [out] " + "result.mp3";
String s = "-i " + "test.wav" + " -i " + "test2.mp3" + " -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout] -map [aout] -ac 2 " + "result.mp3";
```

1) Could I mix two different audio formats (in my case .mp3 & .wav) or they should be equivalent?
2) What is the correct command line for the mixing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Could I mix two different audio formats (in my case .mp3 & .wav)?

Yes. The input format does not matter because it will be fully decoded to PCM audio before being fed to the filter, but you have to be aware of how the various input channels will be mixed to create the channel layout for the output. Read the documentation on the [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filters for more info.

> 2) What is the correct command line for the mixing?

Your command using amerge should work:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -i test2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]" -map "[aout]" -ac 2 result.mp3
```

Or using amix:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -i test2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest[aout]" -map "[aout]" result.mp3
```

Comment: LordNeckbeard, thanks for the help.

Do you have any ideas why after using:

    "-i test.mp3 -i test2.wav - filter_complex '[0:a][1:a]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest[aout]'  -map '[aout]' result.mp3"
I can only hear first track, without any mix?

Comment: @Bogdan I will need to see the complete log from the `ffmpeg` process to provide any suggestions.

Comment: is this the correct way to create a log file?
... result.mp3 2> log.txt

Comment: @Bogdan That can work, but you you may have to add `-y` to confirm output file overriding. Otherwise it may hang awaiting your confirmation. Alternatively use the `-report` option but it is overly verbose. Third option is `FFREPORT` environmental variable: `FFREPORT=file=ffreport.log:level=32 ffmpeg -i input output`.

Comment: my last suggestion didn't work for me. So I need to try other 3 options that you've provided. Thanks

Comment: LordNeckbeard, thanks for your help!! Finally your suggestion with "amix" works for me!! 
Other 2 questions that I have:
1) I want 1st track to be saved with its 30% of volume and 2nd track with 80%. So one just needs to be louder than another. What is the correct way of doing that?
2) During the first run and use of FFMpeg - I am seeing a popup "Downloading FFMpeg  library". Is there any way how I could integrate all that I need (libavutil, libavcodec etc.) directly into Xamarin.Android project and not see this popup?

Comment: @Bogdan 1) You can use the [volume](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) filter: `[0:a]volume=0.3[a0];[1:a]volume=0.8[a1];[a0][a1]amix...` Alternatively, use amerge + [pan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) filter. 2) Sorry, but I don't know anything about Xamarin.Android.